# Unity reverted all my work, any way to fix?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, revert

Sorry if this is one of those questions with a super basic answer. I am BRAND NEW to unity and GitHub as I've just joined my game dev team as a writer and am very slowly learning the ropes. So, here's the issue:

- I've been working on a translation of the game we're building into a different language. All the edits are made in Unity and then committed to a specific branch of the master game on GitHub.
- The other day, I accidentally clicked into the "master" branch (the one without my work) on GitHub while Unity was running. I immediately clicked back into my translation branch, but the damage was done, and ALL my work had disappeared from Unity as the master replaced everything.
- I tried looking up how to revert to a prior version, but as far as I can tell, I was not using Collaborate OR Plastic SCM so I have no idea how to revert to a prior version without these cloud tools.
- Thankfully I do access to my most recent work because I pushed it to GitHub right before this all happened, but I'm wondering: Is there a way I can fix this without having to manually restore everything in Unity myself?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Did you commit anything at any point on your branch?